# "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous" - searching pandas dataframe for NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I'm trying to iterate through all the rows of a pandas `DataFrame` and find the first instance of NaN in a particular column.  E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

for row_index, row in df[:].iterrows():
if pd.isnull(df.ix[:,'one']) == True:
    break
```

But I get: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I thought I was only inspecting one element of the DataFrame at a time, so I don't know what the problem is.  Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: "I thought I was only inspecting one element of the DataFrame at a time": but `df.ix[:,"one"]` is the entire `one` column.  To do what you want in a loop-based fashion, you'd do `if pd.isnull(row["one"]):` do you see the difference?

Comment: Hi.  After applying behzad's answer to my code it printed out the DataFrame 4 times and I got confused.  Then I noticed the mistake you've pointed out.  All fixed now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.index[ df.one.isnull( ) ][ 0 ]
```

gives the index of the first row, which has `null` in column `"one"`

the more efficient way to find the first row would be to define a generator, and take the first element of that generator, like:

```
gen = ( idx for idx in df.index if np.isnan( df.one[ idx ] ) )
```

now `gen.__next__()` will be the first index.

Comment: Great, that fixed one problem.  I've just encountered another but that's because I wrote my loop wrong.  I've solved that one too so I'm all good now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, w/r/t the question, if you debug you will see:

```
ipdb> pd.isnull(df.ix[:,'one'])
a    False
b    False
c    False
d     True
```

So you do have multiple elements. The truth value *is* ambiguous, so if you used .any() you would get True and with .all() you would get False.

The comments addressed the error in the code, I just want to clearly state the any() all() behavior for anyone who comes across this topic by name.